# Maximized windows don't display correctly and don't accept clicks

Tags: windows-7, display

Sometimes my PC has a problem when I maximize a window on Windows 7 and the window doesn't work correctly. I am looking for the cause of this and a fix for it.

When I maximize the window, the frame is drawn but the client area will remain blank (when maximized from a minimized state via the task bar) or it will keep the image from when it was a smaller window (when the title bar is double clicked) or the image just before a dragged window is dropped (at the top edge of the desktop to maximize it).

The maximized window will not handle the mouse correctly. If I click or double click on the window, even on the frame, it actually clicks on what's behind the window, which might be another window that is not maximized or the desktop. Right clicking on the maximized window will bring up the context menu of whatever is behind the window. Even when I hover the mouse over the desktop icons that I can see through the transparent title bar, I can see that those icons become highlighted. I also tested with two maximized windows and the mouse will go through both of them to reach the desktop icons.

When I do a restore window from the taskbar then the window will be a bit smaller and function normally. If I 'Show windows stacked' from the task bar and this window is the only one not minimized, then it will become the full size of the monitor, but it will not be maximized. In this case it works normally and accepts mouse clicks.

My main monitor is 1280 x 1024 and this is where the problem happens. My secondary monitor is 1024 x 768 and when I maximize a window there it's okay.

Restarting the PC will solve the problem. Also, at least once the problem just went away by itself and then came back later.

I checked task manager and there is plenty of RAM available.

Not every program has this problem. At this moment, Windows Explorer, Google Chrome, Google Earth, VLC and Quicken are having the problem but Excel, Word, Outlook, Teamviewer, TightVNC and Command Prompt are not. Obviously these programs are from a variety of sources and this problem doesn't seem to be related to the source of the program.

Update on 2020-05-17. I tried to use the task manager to kill the explorer task with End Task, then start explorer again with New Task. The problem did not get cleared.

Comment: What is display scaling set to? Have you checked for and installed the latest drivers for your video card? This sounds like a screen drawing/rendering issue mostly.

Comment: The scaling is set to Smaller 100% (default). I ran Update Driver Software... in the Device Manager and it says 'The best driver software for your device is already installed.' My device is called Intel(R) HD Graphics Family.

I agree it's a drawing issue. But it's only happening sometimes, on some programs but not all and only when they are maximized on the primary display.

I don't see a way to upload pictures here to show the problem. Is there any way?

Comment: That update process isn't what you want. You need to find you video device details and go to the manufacturer website and find and download the latest drivers they have and install those.

Comment: Ok, I will try that and report back...

Comment: I upgraded from 10.18.14.5067 dated 12/27/2018 to 10.18.14.5117 dated 12/13/2019. Not likely a huge change. The problem is not showing itself now but I did have to reboot for the change to take effect. And as I mention above in my question, that solves the problem temporarily. So I will monitor and update if the problem returns or doesn't return.

Comment: This morning when I woke up, the problem was back.

Comment: This is weird. I now see that some instances of Google Chrome windows have the problem and some others do not. AT the moment, none of the other windows that I have open are showing the problem, only those few Chrome windows. No, also one of my file syncing programs has the problem so not only Chrome.